# How to use view parameter "Keys" for date fields at Domino Data Service REST API

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

**Domino REST API** doesn't return any view data if I use **date** at query parameter "**Keys**". In case of Extension Library REST Control we can use `NotesDateTime()` or `@Date()` to make it work.

But I don't know how to use the same at Domino REST API call. Anybody knows how to use date as key?

This is the the sample url,

https://demodomain.com/demo.nsf/api/data/collections/name/viewName?sortcolumn=DateField&keys=1999-03-24T22:16:17Z

Comment: Can you give an example of how the content of your view column looks like?

Comment: Tell us what you tried because you should be able to use SSJS in for the keys, including the @ functions.

Comment: Thanks Steve,  I want to clarify that I am not using extlib REST control here, I am trying to get data using DAS REST API.   And this is how my view column content looks,  ex:  **01/01/2016**

Comment: Syed, thanks for clarifying. It looks like you have a good answer below. If that works for you, make sure you accept the answer by pushing the green check mark on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the source code for the Domino data service.  The view entries resource (**/{db}/api/data/collections/name/{view}**) always assumes the **keys** parameter is a string.  So apparently it's unable to match any value in a date column.

This behavior could be improved.  Meanwhile, you could work around the limitation by creating a separate sort column with the TEXT representation of the same date.  Use the new column name in the **sortcolumn** parameter and the view entries resource should be able find rows that match the **keys** parameter.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I did follow your suggestion and got what I wanted.